# Symfony2/Doctrine2 Get data from two tables

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm

I have an Alert Class with some data in it.  I then have an Availability class.  In my Availability class I have

```
/**
 * @var \Nick\AlertBundle\Entity\Alert
 *
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Nick\AlertBundle\Entity\Alert")
 * @ORM\JoinColumns({
 *   @ORM\JoinColumn(name="availability_alert_id", referencedColumnName="id")
 * })
 */
private $availabilityAlert;
```

So this is a foreign key back to my Alert class, linked to my Alerts class id.

I am now doing some work on the Availability data, so I have the DQL query

```
public function getAlertAvailability($id)
{
    return $this->getEntityManager()
        ->createQuery(
            'SELECT a.id, a.classLetter, a.flightNumber, a.alertPseudo, a.availability, a.lastUpdated
                FROM NickAlertBundle:Availability a
                WHERE a.availabilityAlert = :id
                ORDER by a.classLetter, a.lastUpdated'
        )
        ->setParameter('id', $id)
        ->getResult();
}
```

The way I call that is like this

```
public function getAvailabilityData(){
        $alerts = $this->em->getRepository('NickAlertBundle:Alert')->getActiveAlertIds();

        if (!$alerts) {
            echo "No Availability";
        }

        foreach($alerts as $alert){
            $alertId = (int)$alert['id'];
            $allAvailability = $this->em->getRepository('NickAlertBundle:Availability')->getAlertAvailability($alertId);
        }
}
```

So I essentially get all my active Alerts Ids, and then pass this to get my Availability for these individual Alerts.

Now I have a couple of problems.

Firstly, in the DQL query I make, I need to also get something from my Alert table (a field called command).  How would I do a join in this query to get this piece of data?

Secondly, with the data that is returned, how do I access availabilityAlert in my Twig file?

**UPDATE**
Attempt at join

```
public function getAlertAvailability()
{
    return $this->getEntityManager()
        ->createQuery(
            'SELECT a.id, a.classLetter, a.flightNumber, a.alertPseudo, a.availability, a.lastUpdated, u.searchCommand
                FROM NickAlertBundle:Availability a
                JOIN a.availabilityAlert u
                ORDER BY a.classLetter, a.lastUpdated'
        )
        ->getResult();
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Doctrine will load that entity as a proxy (for lazy loading) when the Availability entity is loaded.

You can access these via a normal getter / property access, but they will typically be lazy loaded by Doctrine. You can have them joined via a DQL query and the property will be hydrated with all the linked entities already loaded, see [Improving Performance with a Join](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/security/entity_provider.html#improving-performance-with-a-join).

You can then access those associated entities in Twig as any other property.

Comment: What I dont understand is do I use a left join?  Also what should I be joining?

Comment: Instead of loading the ids of the alerts then loading `Availability` entities from there, try adding a method to the repository for `Availability` that loads the entity with the `Alert`s already joined on with the conditions you need (via the DQL technique I linked), then you can get the alerts from the entity via the getter (`getAlerts` or whatever) as you normally would.

Comment: I have updated the question with a pathetic attempt I have made.  a is supposed to be availability and u is for the Alert table.  What I think I need to do is join Availabilities availabilityAlert onto Alerts id field, just struggling to figure out how

Comment: If you look [here](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/dql-doctrine-query-language.html#dql-select-examples) you can see various examples of the syntax for joining and how you can add conditions to the join.

Comment: I have updated my question with something that appears to work.  One thing though; instead of doing all them a.something, I want to just return the whole availability object (so select a, u).  However, if I do this, my browser freezes and my whole virtualbox messes up.  Do you think this is a query problem or virtual box problem?